# Control loop missed its desired rate

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run move_base navigation to a goal on Odroid C1+ board.
But the result is bad, the robot didn't move smoothly.
Here is the result screen recording:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyD-rVA4dKw

And this is my move_base parameter files:

https://github.com/wennycooper/learning_nav/tree/master/config/fake

The strange thing is, if I run the same code on my desktop PC. The result is pretty smooth.

I found the difference is, on my PC, the control loop frequency can reach to 2.5Hz as specified, but it can only reach to ~2.2Hz on Odroid C1+.  I even tried the same test on Raspberry Pi 2, the result is even worse...

Any idea to make it better??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217842/control-loop-missed-its-desired-rate/) by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2015-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-09-19**:
I also tried XU3, the control loop rate can reach >=3 and the result is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is with the cpu and the processing power. As @makokal said I do not think it is related with move_base.

Maybe you should try lowering the costmap resolution, and/or costmap sizes etc. Therefore your navigation stack will require less processing power and memory. However your navigation performance may degrade as a result.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-09-21**:
Thanks for your reply. I tried modify the (both global & local) costmap resolution to 1.0 and local map width x height to 1.0x1.0.  The control rate did slightly increased to 2.45... but it's still not good enough. Any more recommendation??

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-09-21**:
You may try increasing sim_time, sim_granularity and angular_sim_granularity a bit.

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-09-21**:
BTW, I found the system is not very busy in overall. It's a quad-cores CPU and only one core is almost 100% when running move_base.

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-09-22**:
Yes, I tried increasing sim_time=1, sim_granularity=0.5 and angular_sim_granularity=0.5, the result is still not god.  Now I'm afraid that Odroid C1+ is just not powerful enough for move_base....

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually control loop missing its desired means that something is taking longer that you anticipated.  I have no experience with Odroid C1+, how do the specs compare your PC? I think the issue has nothing to do with `move_base` in this case

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1